# driver.wait() throws IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, testing, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

All the variations of wait(...) are throwing the below exception from the following code. What am I doing wrong?

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at LoginPage.main(LoginPage.java:29)

try
        {
            driver.get("http://domain:port/coco/webapp/login/login.faces");

            driver.findElement(By.id("clientCode")).sendKeys("coco");
            driver.findElement(By.id("systemCode")).sendKeys("consumer");
            driver.findElement(By.id("userId")).sendKeys("ffadmin");
            driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");

            driver.findElement(By.className("af_commandButton")).click();
            driver.wait();
            Assert.assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("Administration"));

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can only [`wait`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) on an object if you've acquired the lock for it using `synchronized`.

I don't know whether you're *meant* to use `wait` using WebDriver - if you are, you'd need something like:

```
synchronized (driver)
{
    driver.wait();
}
```

However, if you're waiting for something to occur, it's more likely that there's an alternative method you're meant to be using. Perhaps [`WebDriverWait`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html)?

Comment: Apparently wait is not required from seleniunm 2 onwards as it supports implicit waits. With implicit waits, you only need to use one of the findElement methods, and if the target element does not exist or is not visible, Selenium will wait until it is. Unfortunately this example is out of date, however if you look at some of my more recent examples, hopefully you will find them to be working. http://seleniumexamples.com/blog/examples/selenium-2-examples/

Answer (score 9):

I hope this helps you

```java
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(long time, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit unit);
```

OR

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, long timeOutInSeconds);

WebElement element = wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By locator));
```

Please note that I have not executed this code as I don't have webdriver but I wrote this after referring to javadocs.

Please refer [javadocs](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/) for more details on this.

Comment: There is an error here, the last line should not include the timeout as a parameter for wait.until. At least, not as of the 2015 code (but I can't see why the old version would have that duplication either).

Comment: This worked for me `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);`

Answer (score 2):

`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` is the best solution. Else, you have surround the `driver.wait` by synchronize block

Answer (score 0):

This is a necro, but since there aren't better answers, and someone else might happen by: you're calling the wrong method.

You probably intended to call the selenium method to wait for a condition: 
https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html

What you actually called was the very primitive multithreading method (to wait until someone else has called notify() on your thread): 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code, this will work.

```
synchronized (driver)
{
　　driver.wait(2000);
}
driver.context(NATIVE_APP);
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[@resourceid=‘android:id/button1’]").click();
```