# How to find an element on a webpage using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: python, windows, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I trying to automate a task using Selenium `WebDriver` for FireFox on YouTube.

I have a playlist created on YouTube and I want to get the hyperlink of all the videos in that playlist.

The `html` looks like this:

```
<a href="/watch?v=StJLvbPIvTw&amp;list=PLt5xbw4ekDQssXxfaIfh_XbKe-iuOTZo_&amp;index=1" title="ADELE - Skyfall (Official video HD)" class="yt-uix-tile-link yt-uix-sessionlink" data-sessionlink="feature=plpp_video&amp;ei=RodgUazfOKWlhAHOioGoDA">
    <span class="title video-title" dir="ltr">ADELE - Skyfall (Official video HD)</span>
  </a>
```

I tried finding the element using the `find_by_partial_link_text` but failed.

My ultimate motive is to get the hyperlink for all the videos in the playlist so that i can pass it to next script to access them individually.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Note: I found an answer in SO similar to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121886/accessing-selenium-web-elements-with-python)  but the answer provided here is iterating over a `WebElement` object which throws an exception in my case saying object is not iterable.

**EDIT:**

```
def init():

    d = webdriver.Firefox()
    d.implicitly_wait(15)
    print "in init"
    return d

def youtube(d, uname, pwd):

    link_list = []
    d.get("http://www.youtube.com")
    print "in you"
    signin = d.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Sign in")
    signin.click()

    email = d.find_element_by_id("Email")
    passwo = d.find_element_by_id("Passwd")
    submit = d.find_element_by_id("signIn")

    email.send_keys(uname)
    passwo.send_keys(pwd)
    submit.click()

    list = d.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Playlists")
    list.click()

    play = d.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Fav songs")
    play.click()
    print play

    link_list = d.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="playlist-pane-container"]/div[1]')
    print "done"
    print link_list # prints None here
    hr = link_list.get_attribute("css=a@href")
    print hr
```

Comment: You really need to show what you've tried.

Comment: @RossPatterson added the code I have tried. Any inputs will be immensely appreciated.

Comment: You have 3 uses of `find_element_by_partial_link_text()`.  None of them come anywhere near to matching the HTML fragment you showed.

Comment: @RossPatterson I was first trying to do that with 'find_element_by_partial_text()' but it was not helping, so instead i tried using the xpath to find all the elements like that on the page as suggested on this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121886/accessing-selenium-web-elements-with-python but instead i getting an empty list.

Comment: Any specific reasons for Downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get link by : 
`String hrefSpecs = driver.findelement(By.cssSelector("a.yt-uix-tile-link.yt-uix-sessionlink")).getAttribute("href")`

normally you get

`/watch?v=StJLvbPIvTw&amp;list=PLt5xbw4ekDQssXxfaIfh_XbKe-iuOTZo_&amp;index=1`

so you substring that like :

```
String sublink = hrefSpecs.substring(0,20); // check the 20 i'm not sure
```

and you'll get

```
/watch?v=StJLvbPIvTw
```

since you get this you can write something like that

```
String youtube = "www.youtube.com";
String link = youtube + sublink;
```

and you finally get :   www.youtube.com/watch?v=StJLvbPIvTw

But if you have a page with all links, you'll build something like :

`List<String> listLink = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a.yt-uix-tile-link.yt-uix-sessionlink")).getAttribute("href")`;

and you 'll iterate that with a foreach with previous substring etc. i let you test and tell me if you have problems.

EDIT : `WebElement` is not iterable, `List<WebElement>` or `[]` in your case are iterable. I wrote it in Java, i hope you can "translate" it =)

Answer (score -1):

you can get the link by simple string manipulation.

load the string in a variable, split the string by the spaces, the second element will give you the href + link, remove the href part and you will get the link.

try this

`html = '<a href="/watch?v=StJLvbPIvTw&amp;list=PLt5xbw4ekDQssXxfaIfh_XbKe-iuOTZo_&amp;index=1" title="ADELE - Skyfall (Official video HD)" class="yt-uix-tile-link yt-uix-sessionlink" data-sessionlink="feature=plpp_video&amp;ei=RodgUazfOKWlhAHOioGoDA">
    <span class="title video-title" dir="ltr">ADELE - Skyfall (Official video HD)</span>
  </a>'`

`parts = html.split(" ")`

`link = parts[1][6:-1]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But I have 100+ videos in the playlist and i think it will not be efficient to manually copy the html. I am trying to automate the task

Comment: I thought you had separate file for each video, anyways you can always use string manipulation to extract all the videos' html from the html source of the page.

Comment: Oh, the horror!  This is Selenium code, the API has plenty of methods to make this sort of thing much easier.  Given an element `<a href="...">blah</a>`, something as simple as `for element in driver.find_elements_by_tagname("a"): print element.get_attribute("href");` would do the job.