# Selenium, issue with retrieving url from image object

Tags: python, vb.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working with the application, which I have made test in my old tool (HP QTP), now I need convert it to selenium(python webdriver), I have issue with specific part, during the test flow I receive image with the value, (data is static only for testing), so I know what value I should send for response.
In HP QTP I solved it by 'if conditional' and loop (VB code below):

```
For Each elem As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")
     If elem.GetAttribute("src") = "http://URL/image_1.png" Then
     WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("response").SetAttribute("value", "70")
     End If
     If elem.GetAttribute("src") = "http://URL/image_2.png" Then
     WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("response").SetAttribute("value", "80")
     End If
```

I don't know how it should looks in python. I didn't found equivalent function for "elem.GetAttribute("")" in Python.
Unfortunately I have lack experience with python so I'm looking for solution or hints for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is a get_attribute method available in python API. You need to find the element and be able to perform same action you are doing in vb. Consult [this](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121886/accessing-selenium-web-elements-with-python) is an example how to do it.