# How to get img src in string in selenium using python

Tags: python, image, selenium, src

I have a google search result, something like

```
div class="rc"
    h3 class="r"
        <a href="somelink">
            <img id="idFOO" src="data:somethingFOO" style="...">
        </a>
```

I want to add somethingFOO (or data:somethingFOO) to a string using python & selenium. How can I do that?

Comment: what do you mean you wan to add, do you mean you want to fetch this text and combine with string or you want to add something to this text ?

Comment: I want to put "somethingFOO" in a string. For example I want to be able to do "return string" and the result to be "somethingFOO".

Comment: what have you tried so far, and what's not working?

Comment: I've tried myString=browser.find_element_by_class_name("r").text but I don't get what I want. I get some other text.
I've tried find_element_by_id("idFOO).text and I get nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [accessing selenium web elements with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121886/accessing-selenium-web-elements-with-python)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

what you are interested is not a text, it's an attribute with name src. so if you will do something like that, you won't get what you want.

`find_element_by_id("idFOO").text`

if your html is like this,

```
<input id="demo">hello world </input>
```

then the following code will give you hello world

```
driver.find_element_by_id("demo").text
```

and following code will give you demo

```
driver.find_element_by_id("demo").get_attribute("id")
```

so in your case, it should be

`driver.find_element_by_id("idFOO").get_attribute("src")`

Comment: @cosminp you could select the answer, if it's working so it help others.

Comment: Just did that. :) Quick question if I may, can I do something to look only for a substring in driver.find_element_by_id("idFOO")? I'd like something like driver.find_element_by_id("idF*").

Comment: yes, `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'idF')]")`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
src = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='rc]/h3[@class='r']/a/img").get_attribute("src")
```

P.S.- Used full available xpath to avoid duplicate conflicts on actual DOM.