# how do can i get src link text using selenium?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='a image']/img")
```

the html look like this

```
<div class="a image"><imgsrc="https://cloudfront.net/"></div>
```

how to get the src text ?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-do-i-get-the-src-of-an-image-in-selenium#:~:text=To%20fetch%20any%20attribute%20in,getAttribute(%22src%22).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45215992

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get img src in string in selenium using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45215992/how-to-get-img-src-in-string-in-selenium-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
element = browser.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='a image']/img")
src = element.get_attribute("src")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("img").get_attribute('src'))
```