# Getting the URL of the current page using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm attempting to get the URL of the currently open page.  I am using Selenium WebDriver and Java.

I am accessing the current URL via:

```
WebDriver driver = new WebDriver();
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
```

however, the URL does not appear to actually reflect where I currently am.

My current test case involves going to the NYT website and then clicking on the "Technology" link.  However, `url` appears to always be `http://www.nytimes.com/`, regardless of the URL that is displayed in the address bar.

How do I actually access the value of the URL that's in the address bar so I can tell what page I'm actually on?

Comment: just curious why cant you directly access the technology link? why di you want to go to home page and click?

Comment: My program is iteratively exploring the page by following links - but it would be useful to be able to know where it has actually been so that it doesn't click on the same links over and over again.

Comment: Using `HtmlUnitDriver` it, indeed, does not change the URL. Strange. In IE8 on Windows XP SP3, everything runs smoothly, though. What is your browser (did you try the others?), OS and Selenium version?

Comment: I know the OP asked about Java, but for Python/Robot Framework, at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833624/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-robot-framework someone recommended `GetLocation`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Put sleep. It will work. I have tried.
The reason is that the page wasn't loaded yet.
Check this question to know how to wait for load  - [Wait for page load in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868439/wait-for-page-load-in-selenium)

Comment: Sleep() should probably almost never be used for waiting for the page load. I think it's quite obvious why (network speed, cpu speed, web server response time, to name a few) and there are wait-related methods in the web driver for exactly those reasons, so always use those instead of sleep().