# How to get the current URL in Robot framework?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

When the 'apply' link is clicked, it opens a new browser in Robot framework. How to get current url of that page? Here is the code:

```
Open Server     
Set Browser Implicit Wait   60  
Go To   ${server}/jobs  

Element Should Be Visible   xpath=.//*[@id='txtjobsearch']  

Input Text  xpath=.//*[@id='txtjobsearch']  ${job Title search}

Element Should Contain  xpath=(.//*[@class='clearfix tit-job']/div)[1]  ${Job title}

Element Should Be Visible   xpath=(.//*[@class='btn btn-sm btn-primary btnApply'])[1]   

Click Element   xpath=(.//*[@class='btn btn-sm btn-primary btnApply'])[1]
```

After this line, it opens a new window. How to get url of newly opened page and do actions like input text?

```
Set Browser Implicit Wait   20  

Wait Until Page Contains Element    xpath=.//*[@class='text-primary']
```

Comment: If give Get Location command  is given  it doesnt  gives the url of the newly opened browser after the apply button is clicked .

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
${url}=   Get Location
```

Answer (score 4):

getting the current URL is easy using the [Execute Javascript](https://robotframework-seleniumlibrary.googlecode.com/hg/doc/SeleniumLibrary.html#Execute%20Javascript) SeleniumLibrary keyword:

```
${url} =  Execute Javascript  return window.location.href;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the Select Window keyword?

http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Select%20Window

```
Click Link  popup_link  # opens new window  
Select Window   popupName       
Title Should Be Popup Title     
Select Window           # Chooses the main window again
```

It seems like you wish to verify the url of the new window which should be easily possible with the following:

```
Select Window | url=https://google.com
```

Obviously you need to replace the above url with what you're expecting.  Let us know how you get on.

Comment: Actually my url will be changing .For Example https;//www.google.com/75 like this.so wat can i do. If url is constant i can directly give url=www.google.com

Comment: http://www.google.com/job/35 like this it will be                                                      http://www.google.com/job/36 like this it will be changing.in this case how to get the url ?

Comment: Can you explain more about the mechanism?  For example is this clicking a 'user' or something?  In which case you can grab the url from the link you click, then check that it is equal to the url in the new window?  Or is this dynamically generated?

Comment: Select Window  |  url=   , gives a message, invalid time string. what is that?