# Method getCurrentUrl(); returns incorrect URL

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm actually just starting to learn Java with Selenium, and I can't receive the current URL. Selenium returns the start URL, not the current one.

It looks like, `implicitlywait()` does not work, or did I do something else wrong?

```
package SeleniumPackage;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SeleniumClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.get("https://learn.letskodeit.com/p/practice");

WebElement benzRadioBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("benzradio"));
benzRadioBtn.click();

WebElement hondaRadioBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("hondaradio"));
hondaRadioBtn.click();
WebElement bmwRadioBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("bmwradio"));
bmwRadioBtn.click();
WebElement benzCheckBox = driver.findElement(By.id("benzcheck"));
benzCheckBox.click();
Select dropdown = new Select (driver.findElement(By.id("carselect")));
dropdown.selectByValue("honda");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("product"));
System.out.println(element.getText());

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Terms of Use")).click();

String currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();  
System.out.println(currentURL);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the URL of the current page using Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549647/getting-the-url-of-the-current-page-using-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add some explicit wait after clicking the "Terms of Use" Link else add some delay.

**Modified Code:**

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Terms of Use")).click();
//Added Newly
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Terms"));

String currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
```

Comment: this is also correct, but we can also use verficaion points :P

Comment: Yeah . But sometimes, page title function also will not give the current  page title correctly. So, It is always better to add some wait after the page load action and then we can add the verification

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected behaviour, since you are clicking on "Terms of Use" of the iframe, which doesn't redirect your URL (just change the iframe's)

[image]

I suggest to use xpath to find the desired element like this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[@class=' video no-videoautoplay']/body/div[@class='view-school']/footer[@class='bottom-menu bottom-menu-inverse']/div[@class='container']/div[@class='row']/div[@class='col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 footer-column'][2]/ul[@class='list-unstyled']/li[1]/a"));
```

Comment: How did you get this Xpath? Thx.

Comment: Through and Chrome extention, i don't remember the name at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can match with the title if the title is matched then print current URL,it always gives you correct URL

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
System.out.println("Ready to launch the browser");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/sankalp.gupta/Desktop/JAVASELN/chromedriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://learn.letskodeit.com/p/practice");

WebElement benzRadioBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("benzradio"));
benzRadioBtn.click();

WebElement hondaRadioBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("hondaradio"));
hondaRadioBtn.click();
WebElement bmwRadioBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("bmwradio"));
bmwRadioBtn.click();
WebElement benzCheckBox = driver.findElement(By.id("benzcheck"));
benzCheckBox.click();
Select dropdown = new Select (driver.findElement(By.id("carselect")));
dropdown.selectByValue("honda");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("product"));
System.out.println(element.getText());

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Terms of Use")).click();
if(driver.getTitle().contains("Practice | Let's Kode It"))
    {
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());

    }
}
```

Comment: This method does not give me the desired result.Thx.

Comment: what result u want

Comment: Just get current url, after changing iframe.

Answer (score 0):

As you have invoked `click()` in the previous line, next to retrieve the *URL* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* in conjunction with *ExpectedConditions* method [**`urlContains(java.lang.String fraction)`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#urlContains-java.lang.String-) as follows :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.urlContains("partial_text_of_url"));
System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
```

**Note** : You need to remove the `implicitlywait()` because as per the [documentation](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) :

> Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times. For example setting an implicit wait of 10 seconds and an explicit wait of 15 seconds, could cause a timeout to occur after 20 seconds.