# Element is no longer valid freeze in IE8

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-8, selenium-webdriver, browserstack

The following test works fine with IE7, IE9, Chrome, Firefox and Safari. But it freezes in IE8. IE8 doesn't do the last command. How can I fix it to run on IE8?

```
@driver.navigate.to 'http://www.berge-meer.de'
@driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 1
@driver.find_element(:link, "Schnäppchen").click
@driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 1
@driver.find_element(:partial_link_text, "Alle Reisedetails").click
@driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 3
@driver.find_element(:partial_link_text, "Termine").click
```

Browserstack stops with the following screen:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you check this link 
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp.

In your case, you clicked a button, found the element and then page changed due to the previous click action. Thus you got "Element is not valid".

This might help: [Wait for page load in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868439/wait-for-page-load-in-selenium)