# Selenium WebDriver Automation for Vaadin components

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, vaadin

I am using Selenium Java WebDriver to automate a Vaadin based web application. When I navigate to a page and click a button it opens up another small window which does not look like a popup to me. It seems the subwindow is dynamically added to the main html.

Does anyone have any idea on how to identify Vaadin elements in Selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you creating test be sure to run this test after the browser is open. Sometimes test starts, but browser is not open. I put `Thread.sleep(1000);` in `@Before` class, to be sure chrome is open.

```
@Before
public void openBrowser() throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://localhost:8000");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

and then

```
@Test
public void testLoginFormExists() {
    WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
    ...
}
```

or even better, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9430377/1168786

Answer (score 1):

try with

`driver.findElement(By.className("v-window"))` for the entire window or
`driver.findElement(By.className("v-window-contents"))` for the window content.

Comment: it is v-window-contents. But no luck using that as well- org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"v-window-contents"}