# Clicking JavaScript links in Selenium WebDriver and Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver in Python and I got stuck trying to activate a javascript button.

What I need to do here is to click the Go to Previous Month button twice so that I have August 2014.
And then I need to click on one of the days.

The images below show the code. Please tell me if I need to provide more info.

[image]

THIS IS THE "GO TO PREVIOUS MONTH BUTTON" + INSPECT ELEMENT

[image]

AND HERE I'VE CLICKED ON THE 1ST OF AUGUST + INSPECT ELEMENT ON "1"

How do I do it?

Comment: Find a element by title using css selectors and do the click() event on the returned element?

Comment: How do I use the css selectors? I'm a bit of a n00b...

Comment: Cool! No problem - clarified the answer in the Answer section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First find your element with CSS selectors (you need to be familiar how CSS selectors work - this is prerequisite for most web development):

```
elem = webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title='Go to previous month']")[0]
```

[Related WebDriver documentantion](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html).

Then when you get your elem (there might paeg loading time, etc. issues you need to deal with) you can click it.

```
 elem.click()
```

See also: [Wait for page load in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868439/wait-for-page-load-in-selenium)

[Related click() documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html).

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that there are actually two calendars on that page, and both have "Go to the previous month" as title of the "<" button... I guess I need to be more specific exactly where I want to press the button. Using xpath?

Comment: `find_element_by_css_selector()` returns multiple elements. Just pick the first or the last one.

Comment: It's taken a few days, but I finally got it :D Thanks!