# Javascript functions and links are not working in Selenium (Python)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am writing Selenium tests for my applications and for my own use. Every time I tried to reach Javascript functions or click buttons in the source code, I got errors. Here is the basic example:

```
            <font class="bodytextdark"></font>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <table width="90%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" bordercolor="#111111" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse"></table>
            <br></br>
            <font color="red"></font>
            <form action="stuinfgpacalc.asp" method="POST" name="gpaform">
                <p>
                    <a href="Javascript:window.close()">

                    Close

                    </a>
                    <a href="Javascript:window.print()">

                    Print

                    </a>
                </p>
                <table width="90%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" bordercolor="#111111" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse"></table>
            </form>
```

I tried to click Print button via code stated below:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.selenium = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.selenium.maximize_window()

def test_get_gpa_calc_result(self):
    ........

    """
    Print the form.
    """
    self.selenium.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href= "Javascript:window.print()"]').click()
```

I got the error: 
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@href= \"Javascript:window.print()\"]"}
Stacktrace

I also tried to reach button via "Print" name too, but it doesn't work.

I checked every solution in here like that one: [Clicking JavaScript links in Selenium WebDriver and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377723/clicking-javascript-links-in-selenium-webdriver-and-python) ,but it doesn't work for me. Any suggestions are more than welcomed!

Comment: Have you tried giving the link an id and selecting by id?  Also, is selenium waiting until the page DOM has loaded?

Comment: Yes, I tried giving id too. I am reaching the page when it stops working, so I guees Selenium loads it properly.

Comment: What I mean is, you may need to tell Selenium to wait until the element is present.  Take a look at http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits

Comment: Can you share the full code for test_get_gpa_calc_result? There is likely a step or missing step there which is causing your  NoSuchElementException, since the xpath is correct for the HTML sample you provided. Like raduation said, you may need to add a wait command.

Comment: @Onur  `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Print')]").click()`