# How to make selenium wait for the page to fully load in Selenium - wrapper for Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, vba

What code or function for Selenium - wrapper for Excel VBA to be used so that the program will wait for the page to fully load then execute other commands?

Comment: what do you mean by "fully load"? Do you mean the accessibility of a certain element (element is displayed)?

Comment: i meant that all the elements are displayed and editable. In the case of firefox, if you look on the Tab of the page you are viewing, the circulating thing is no longer visible.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer this waiting for the "circulating thing" is done already natively by Selenium. What exactly do you want to achieve later down the road. I guess your problem is actually a different one.

Answer (score 6):

The latest version waits implicitly that the targeted element is present before executing the required action. For instance, driver.FindElementById("...").Click will by default try to find the element during 3 seconds before throwing an error.

This implicit waiting can be defined globally:

```
driver.Timeouts.ImplicitWait = 5000 ' 5 seconds
```

As well as individually :

```
driver.FindElementById("id", timeout:=10000).Click  ' implicitly wait of 10sec
driver.FindElementById("id", timeout:=0).Click  ' no implicit waiting
```

To set the timeout for the server that runs the browser:

```
driver.Timeouts.Server = 120000 ' 2 mins
```

To get the latest version in date working with the above example: https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/latest

Answer (score 2):

Hi using this Reference [wait-for-page-load-in-selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868439/wait-for-page-load-in-selenium)

I developed this code:

```
While Selenium.ExecuteScript("return document.readyState") <> "complete"
    Selenium.Wait (5000)
Wend
```

It looks that the best way is pseudocode: `Wait until a specific FindElementbyId appears`. The solution presented is a general approach.

Answer (score 2):

While Florent B's answer is as usual correct what I'd like to add further to that is that there is another piece of code that you might want to add to directly address the problem of increasing the PageLoad in addition to setting the Server Timeouts of the selenium browser:

```
'At the beginning of the code
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

driver.Timeouts.PageLoad = 500000 'this is the piece of code that worked for me
driver.Timeouts.Server = 500000

'At the end of the code
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

The pageload code makes sure that the browser continues to wait until the page is fully loaded with all the data that needs to get loaded in it.

Further, if you would need to increase the time to as much as 500 seconds as highlighted in the code you may also want to disable alerts in Excel as highlighted in code above

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer

Selenium  (also the ExcelVBA wrapper) does this for you. It waits for the [DOM `readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.readyState) to signal that it is complete.

In case of the Excel-Wrapper this will be done when calling `driver.start`

## BUT

This won't help you if you have AJAX-calls or Elements that load via JavaScript and so forth.

There you will need to implement **implicit and explicit waits** to check if the element you are trying to interact with is already existent or even displayed.

It makes no sense to wait for ALL elements to be visible if you want to interact with a certain element. In this case you should just wait for this element to be displayed and then interact with this element.

*If you would elaborate more on your actual problem, we could give you much more detailed advice.*

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Basically my problem is that i loaded a URL then it takes about a minute to load completely. By the time it loads completely, I already received an error saying  "Run-time error '101': WebRequestTimeout: No Response from the server within 30000 seconds..." the code i used was   driver.Start "firefox"
  driver.Get url, 240000, False driver.FindElementById("login_form").WaitDisplayed

Comment: have you tried: driver.start "firefox", url   ? Have you debugged when exactly your code times out? I mean if he passes the "get url" part or if he times out there already?

Comment: it passes the Get URL then he times out already indicating this error " Run-time error '101': WebRequestTimeout: No Response from the server within 30000 seconds.."

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem as well. I have tried both implicit and explicit waits, but have not been able to get the timeout to hold off longer than 30 seconds. I use two workarounds.

The first is klunky but simple: after my `.get` or `.click` event that initiates the page load I pause the code using a messagebox: `msgBox "Wait for page to load then click OK."`

The second is a bit more refined. If I know my page usually takes 50 seconds to load I will put in a set wait period of say, 45 seconds, then have the script verify that a certain element has loaded before continuing:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)

sub LongLoad()
Dim driver As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
Dim By As New By, Assert As New Assert, Verify As New Verify, Waiter As New Waiter
dim YesNo as boolean

driver.Start "chrome", "https://super.secret.com/"
driver.setImplicitWait 5000
driver.setTimeout 120000

driver.Get "/heroLogin"
driver.findElementByName("USER").Clear
driver.findElementByName("USER").SendKeys "user"
driver.findElementByName("PASSWORD").Clear
driver.findElementByName("PASSWORD").SendKeys "pass"
driver.findElementById("Button").Click

'pause for 45 seconds (see if you can hold your breath)
Sleep 45000

'poll for the presence of an element. In my case a certain string of    
'text is good enough. 
driver.verifyTextPresent ("Enterprise Reporting")

'now you're ready to go.
```

`.verifyTextPresent` also has a timeout of 30 seconds, so you still have to use the sleep function first for slow page loads.