# How to assert that image has been uploaded with Capybara?

Tags: ruby, capybara

Let's say I have a form where user can create a post with an image attached to it. I want to make sure the image attached is displayed on the next page:

```
visit url
fill_in the_form
click_on 'Create'
assert_selector '.post'
post = Post.first
img = page.find '.post .image'
assert_equal post.file.thumb.url, URI(img[:src]).path
```

But I'm told asserting against database objects in system tests is to be avoided. What do I do then?

Comment: Do you enter an image name during `fill_in the_form`? Could you just write an assertion that an image with that name is present (or does the database rename it)?

Comment: Yep, I attach image to a form during `fill_in the_form` phase. Then, generally, filename may change after image having been uploaded. But well, that will probably do. Care to turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as there's no "complex" file renaming happening on the backend, you  already know the uploaded filename when populating the form:

```
fill_in the_form
```

Therefore, you could assert that the page contains an image with this name (perhaps using an `xpath`).

If there is trivial file renaming (e.g. replacing spaces with hyphens), then you could either (ideally) just choose a filename that does not change, or reproduce the renaming in your test.

Comment: @x-yuri This is 100% correct - and rather than doing the finds and then assert_equal on the result should probably be written as `assert_selector('.post .image[src="expected source"])` or    `assert_selector('.post .image'){ |img| img[:src] =~ /regex for expected path/ }` or whatever comparison you need to do in the filter block.  This way all of the checking for a matching element occurs inside the assert_selector which will wait/retry and prevent flaky tests if you have dynamically updating pages

Comment: Can you elaborate on this one bit? Are you saying that it's not safe to do `img = page.find '.post .image'; assert_equal post.file.thumb.url, URI(img[:src]).path`? As I understand it, `find` waits for image to appear on the page. After which I can safely assert against its attributes, can't I?

Comment: @x-yuri Assuming there is only one '.post .image'  element on the page, and that once it appears its attributes won't change, then it is safe.  However, by including the filtering in the find/assert it can handle the case of checking for a specific '.post .image' element when there are multiples and/or if the element is added to the page with a temporary `src` attribute that then gets updated to the correct one when an ajax request returns, etc.