# Wait for page to fully load with webdriverjs

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

What's the best way to wait for a page to fully load using selenium-webdriver for javascript? I noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868439/wait-for-page-load-in-selenium) is quite similar but I need an implementation in javascript.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com');

// Wait for the page to fully load here...
// Something like this...
// driver.wait(...);

// Then do other stuff here

driver.quit();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait for page load in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868439/wait-for-page-load-in-selenium)

Comment: Thanks @naveenkumar. I was looking for JavaScript specific implementation but yes, you are right, it is quite similar to what I ended up using.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found that this works for what I needed.

```
driver.get('http://www.google.com');

driver.wait(function() {
  return driver.executeScript('return document.readyState').then(function(readyState) {
    return readyState === 'complete';
  });
});

// Do stuff after page load here
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to post.  That's what I use and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is a solution for both the case where a click brings the user to a page in the same tab and a solution where the click opens the new page in a new browser tab


  /* waitForPageLoad
   * Get the Page ID before the click and after the click. Until the Page id from the first page
   * is no longer equal to the page id of the second page, then we know after a click of a link
   * that the new page is not yet loaded. The timeout will try this until id A is not equal to id B, or timeout.
   * @param {int} timeout
   * @param {string} link
   * @param {string} expectedTitle
   * @return {bool}
   */
  async waitForPageLoad(timeout, link, expectedTitle) {
    let oldHTMLId;
    let newHTMLId;
    let titleWaitingFor;
    const oldHtmlElement = await this.driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.tagName('html')));
    await link.click();
    await this.driver.wait(async () => {
      const actualTitle = await this.driver.getTitle();
      titleWaitingFor = actualTitle;
      const newHtmlElement = await this.driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.tagName('html')));
      const newHtmlElementId = await newHtmlElement.getId();
      const oldHtmlElementId = await oldHtmlElement.getId();
      oldHTMLId = oldHtmlElementId;
      newHTMLId = newHtmlElementId;
      return newHtmlElementId !== oldHtmlElementId
      && actualTitle.includes(expectedTitle);
    }, timeout);
    return oldHTMLId !== newHTMLId && titleWaitingFor.includes(expectedTitle);
  }


//This is what I use if the click opens the Page into another browser tab

  /* getWindowHandlesAndExpetedTitle
   * This function waits for the new window handle after a click instead of using a sleep.
   * Once the expected title of the new window is confirmed, the expected title and url are returned.
   * @param expeted title
   * @return string Page Title and url { title: returnTitle, url: currentUrl }.
   */
  async getWindowHandlesAndExpectedPageInfo(expectedTitle, waitTimeout = 6000) {
    try {
      await this.waitForWindowHandleCount(2);
      let returnHandles;
      let returnTitle;
      await this.driver.wait(async () => {
        const handles = await this.driver.getAllWindowHandles();
        returnHandles = handles;
        await this.driver.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
        const actualTitle = await this.driver.getTitle();
        returnTitle = actualTitle;
        return actualTitle.includes(expectedTitle);
      }, waitTimeout);
      const currentUrl = await this.driver.getCurrentUrl();
      await this.driver.close();
      await this.driver.switchTo().window(returnHandles[0]);
      return { title: returnTitle, url: currentUrl };
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`Function: getWindowHandlesAndExpectedPageInfo failed ${err}`);
      const handles = await this.driver.getAllWindowHandles();
      await this.driver.close();
      await this.driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
      return null;
    }
  }

  /* waitForWindowHandleCount
   * This function is a wait for the epected number of window handles to be present.
   * @param int
   */
  async waitForWindowHandleCount(count, waitTimeout = 6000) {
    try {
      await this.driver.wait(async () => {
        const handles = await this.driver.getAllWindowHandles();
        return handles.length === count;
      }, waitTimeout);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`Function: waitForWindowHandleCount failed ${err} `);
    }
  }
```