# Selenium: Wait for Tomcat to start

Tags: selenium, tomcat, wait

I am aware of the Wait mechanisms in Selenium (e.g. [Wait for page load in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868439/wait-for-page-load-in-selenium)) but my problem is slightly different:

How to wait until Tomcat is up and running? A wait-for-page-load-mechanism won't help: the browser actually loads a page, but it's a "Problem loading page", "Unable to connect" etc. error page.

Which mechanism to use to wait for the actual page to load and to reload-and-wait again if necessary (i.e. an error page is loaded)? I mean: I can wait for a particular DOM element to load (an OK-ish solution but not that generic), but I still need to reload if the error page shows up.

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Right now I am trying to put the wait-for-a-DOM-element in a loop and reload before every loop iteration. Guess that should work just fine. But in case someone has a cleaner, more generic way - I would appreciate sharing it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in function in selenium to handle "Problem loading page" or "Unable to connect" you have to handle it yourself.

Comment: I solved it manually: checking for a particular DOM element to show up in loop. Within each loop iteration the execution halts for a few seconds to wait until the page builds up & after each iteration the page is refreshed.