# python selenium - click button and get page_source

Tags: python, selenium

I currently click a button into a new window:

```
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'test';", browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email-signup-email-address"]'))
input_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="submittracking"]')
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].target="_blank";', input_button.find_element_by_xpath('./ancestor::form'))
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', input_button)
```

but must `time.sleep(10)` before asking `browser.page_source` **otherwise the page does not load fully**

Other articles/posts suggest to use seleniums `explicit wait` but this asks to provide an element to wait for such as `visibilityOfAllElements()` or some specific element. I would like to get the **ALL** the page_source and am not looking to identify any elements.

How can I make `browser.page_source` work as it normally does (when not clicking into a new window)?

Comment: you can wait until state is completed, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868439/wait-for-page-load-in-selenium

Comment: Do you mean, readyState? I may look into this further. Curious if it has a timeout built in. Also the link is mostly in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wait for page loaded (`document.readyState == 'complete'`) as below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(lambda browser: browser.execute_script("return document.readyState;") == "complete")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some timeout for the page load like below:

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
```