# Where do I get the IWait and IWebDriver classes for Java Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11356234/5100278) answer gives an example on how to wait in Java selenium webdriver, but where do you get those classes and packages such as `IWait`, `IWebDriver`, and `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait` ?

Answer (score 1):

### C#:

- `IWait`: `IWait` is one of the interfaces within [`OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI Namespace`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/N_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI.htm)
- `IWebDriver`: [`IWebDriver`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebDriver.htm) is the interface which defines the interface through which the user controls the browser.
- `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait`: [`OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/N_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI.htm) is the namespace which contains the following:

  - `DefaultWait<T>` Class
  - `ExpectedConditions` Class
  - `LoadableComponent<T>` Class
  - `LoadableComponentException` Class
  - `PopupWindowFinder` Class
  - `SelectElement` Class
  - `SlowLoadableComponent<T>` Class
  - `SystemClockDefaultWait<T>` Class
  - `UnexpectedTagNameException` Class
  - `WebDriverWait` Class
  - `IClock` Interface
  - `ILoadableComponent` Interface
  - `IWait<T>` Interface

### Java

- `Wait<F>`: [`Wait<F>`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Wait.html) is the generic interface for waiting until a condition is true or not null. The condition may take a single argument of type.
- `WebDriver`: [`WebDriver`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) is the main interface to use for testing, which represents an idealised web browser.
- `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui`: [`org.openqa.selenium.support.ui`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Wait.html) contains the **`Interface Wait<F>`**.

Comment: So I can't use it in a Java program since it's C#?

Comment: @Kingamere Yes, _Java_ and _C#_ are completely two different _Language Binding Art_ to work with _Selenium_.

Comment: Then how come that answer that I linked to is giving C# code when the question asks for Java code?

Comment: It also gives Ruby and Python code, people like to drop in additional information that's not always asked for.