# How to ask Selenium to wait for page load and then check the URL?

Tags: java, selenium

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868439/wait-for-page-load-in-selenium), which is a combination of `wait + findElementBy`.
But, my question is slightly different, since i need to **check for URL** (rather than element) after page loaded completely.

I already tried the below solution but **it is not working** for me:

```
public void checkCurrentURL(String expectedURL) {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // 5 seconds delay to load the page
    String realURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    System.out.println("------------------------------------URL is: "+realURL);
    Assert.assertTrue(realURL.equals(expectedURL));

}
```

And here is my selenium version:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

---

**Update:**
Thanks to @Guy when i use the below  method:

```
public void checkCurrentURL(String expectedURL) {

        new WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
                new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                        return d.executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
                    }   
                }
            );

        String realURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println("------------------------------------URL is: "+realURL);
        Assert.assertTrue(realURL.equals(expectedURL));

    }
```

It complains with:

```
The method until(Function<WebDriver,T>) in the type WebDriverWait is not applicable for the arguments ()
```

Here is [the repository](https://github.com/salman-/Friday/blob/master/pom.xml).

I updated the selnium to `3.14.0` since `3.142.6` does not work for me.

Answer (score -3):

`implicitlyWait` is used to configure the maximum lookup time when searching `WebElement`, it's not relevant here and will effect the `driver` from now on, not only in the method scope.

You can use `WebDriverWait` and check the `document.readyState`

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, pageLoadTimeout).until(
    new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
            return d.executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }   
    }
);
```

As a side note, version 3.4.0 is quite old (~2.5 years old). Consider update to version 3.142.6 (the newest not alpha version).

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara it might be due to the Selenium version. I added another solution.

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara I removed the first `return`, check now.

Comment: `The method executeScript(String) is undefined for the type WebDriver`

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara this due to the old Selenium version. If you aren't going to upgrade you need to use `JavascriptExecutor`: `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(...);`

Comment: I updated it to `3.14.0` since, i `3.142.6` does not work for me. Here is my POM:
https://github.com/salman-/Friday/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara You need to update `selenium-support` as well.

Comment: Could you please remove your answer, so i can delete my question?