# Test script is not wait in specific page

Tags: c#, selenium, timeout

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@class = 'search-box']")).SendKeys("Samsung");
Console.WriteLine("confirm!");

driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@class = 'search-icon']")).Click();
Console.WriteLine("confirm!");

driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("fvrt-btn")).Click();
Console.WriteLine("confirm!");

driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@class = 'link-text']/div/div/div/div[a]/div/div/div")).Click();
Console.WriteLine("confirm!");

driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("ufvrt-btn")).Click();
Console.WriteLine("confirm!");
```

// this line is not working, test script is not waiting at specific page. ***driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);***

Comment: `ImplicitWait` is used to wait x seconds for an element to be found on the current page. You are doing `.Click` on multiple elements, some of which may navigate to another page. So, in short, `ImplicitWait` isn't going to prevent the browser navigation.

Comment: It looks like you may need to wait for a page to load before executing some of your code blocks, you can read more about awaiting a page load here [wait for page load in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868439/wait-for-page-load-in-selenium)

Comment: thx i wil check it

Comment: `ImplicitWait` should only be defined once in your code, not every time you want to find an element.  You are mixing `ImplicitWait` with the usage of `ExplicitWait`

Comment: @JD2775 Sometimes there is a need to change implicit waiting period, but it is in rare cases. In general it is correct, implicit wait is defined once, in the beginning of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use explicit waits instead of implicit. Try this:

```
WebDriverWait wait;
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element));
```

where `element` is the element locator, for example `By.XPath(".//*[@class = 'search-box']")` on the second line of your code.
The wait timeout is usually set to 30 seconds to allow the page to be loaded completely.