# Login Pop-Up Using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, selenium-webdriver

How do I handle the login pop up window using Selenium Webdriver 4.0 beta? Here's my scenario:

1. Navigate to web app.
2. Web app detects I am not logged in, and redirects to an SSO site
3. SSO site then detects I am not logged in, and shows a login popup window.
4. Redirected back to web app on successful login.

P.S.: I have tried the different solutions offered in previous similar questions but nothing seems to work for me. Code below (I am quite new to Selenium testing so any pointers will be appreciated).

```
     public class LoginTest {
     public static void main(String[] args){

         //Setting the driver path
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path");
        
        //Creating WebDriver instance
         WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
         
         //Navigate to web page
         driver.get("https://url");
         
         //Maximising window
         driver.manage().window().maximize();
         
         //Locating web element
         WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
         WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
         WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.name("submit"));
         
         
         //Performing actions on web elements
         username.sendKeys("email");
         password.sendKeys("password");
         login.click();       
         
         //Closing browser session
         driver.quit();
         
         }
}
```

Comment: have you got any issue?

Comment: @YaDavMaNish yes, the login doesn't work.

Comment: can you give the URL for the login page?

Comment: The issue could be that the SSO website uses a lot of AJAX on load which is why the WebDriver may not know when it has completely loaded thus before the popup shows up the control flow of the program has been passed from driver.get() to the next line in your program & the desired action is not achieved.

Comment: @YaDavMaNish I'm afraid I can't as it's an official one. Here's the issue. The login popup is displayed, however I cant get past that. The popup just stays up - empty and not populated. No errors are displayed either.

Comment: @JumsA. So share the error details

Comment: @dope interesting... any suggestions on how to get around this please?

Comment: @YaDavMaNish no console error.

Comment: @JumsA. ok then try to use explicitWait

Comment: @JumsA. have a look at this -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868439/wait-for-page-load-in-selenium

Comment: @dope thanks both. I’ll give that a try now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you should give it a try using `explicitWait`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    //Navigate to web page
    driver.get("https://url");
    
    //Maximising window
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
    //Locating web element and performing the action
    new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("email"))).sendKeys("");
    new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("password"))).sendKeys("");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("submit"))).click();
   
    //Closing browser session
    driver.quit();
    
    }
}
```