# Selenium script too slow with new FirefoxDriver()

Tags: java, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I doing automation on a particular website(say xyz.com). When I open the URL manually, it lands me onto a login page as expected and I am able to login there as well.
However, when I am automating the scenario by creating new instance of Firefox using new FirefoxDriver(), login page opens quickly but; when I click on login button it takes almost 2 minutes to navigate to a homepage.
I tried using a new profile but it didnt help. 
I am using Selenium 2.44.0 on MAC with Java(Eclipse). 
Please help.

Comment: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Selenium. What I ended up doing was making the webdriver wait till the page title changes(to homepage) using Expected Conditions.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains(": My Expected Page title"));
```

I would suggest you to have a look here:

1. [driver.wait() throws IllegalMonitorStateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858743/driver-wait-throws-illegalmonitorstateexception/5865445#5865445)

   2. [Wait for page load in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868439/wait-for-page-load-in-selenium)